# BarChart убрать квадрат снизу и фон

Tags: java, android, kotlin

может ли кто подказать, как убрать этот квадрат снизу и убрать полностью фон ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

Comment: Этот "квадрат внизу" называется legend. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend

Comment: фон редактировать можно через background в xml

Comment: @Andrew, имеется ввиду не только сам фон, но и полоски разделения

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, спасибо за наводку, а метода на отключение не знаете ? Пока что не могу найти

Comment: Там все написано: `Sets the Legend enabled or disabled. If disabled, the Legend will not be drawn.`

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления Legend

```
val l: Legend = dynamicsGraph.legend
l.isEnabled = false
```